# javascript validation code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

This seems repeated question but please take a look and try to answer.
My javascript validation function is not working. 
Javascript code is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z ]{3,20}$/;
   var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}
  (?:\.  [a-z]{2})?)$/i 

var ck_mobile = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
var ck_address =  /^[A-Za-z0-9-,]{40,100}$/;


function validate(myform){
var name = myform.fullname.value;
var email = myform.email.value;
var mobile = myform.mobile.value;
var address = myform.address.value;



 var errors = [];

if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid Name .";
  }

  if (!ck_email.test(email)) {
   errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid email address.";
  }
 if (!ck_username.test(mobile)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid 10 digit mobile number .";
  }

 if (!ck_password.test(address)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid address min 40 char.";
  }



 if (errors.length > 0) {
  reportErrors(errors);
  return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 function reportErrors(errors){
 var msg = "Please Enter Valid Data...\n";
 for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
  var numError = i + 1;
  msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
  }
  alert(msg);
 }
  </script>
```

I have two button 1)submit and 2)cancel
I want when i click submit button,validate function will call and when i click cancel it goes to back to the page.

HTML form

```
<form action="addorder.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform"  >

                    <!-- Form -->
                    <div class="form">
                        <?php   
                       if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
                       {
                       ?> 
                        <div class="msg msg-ok"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];?></strong></div>
                    <?php } ?>      
 <label>Full name<span>(Required Field)</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="fullname"class="field size1"/>
   </p>
              <p>

                                <label>Email<span>     (Required Field)</span>
                                <input type="text" class="field size1" name="email"/> 
                                </label>
              </p>  

               <p>

                                <label>Mobile<span>(Required Field)</span>
                                <input type="text" class="field size1" name="mobile"/> 
                                </label>
              </p>

                        <p>

                                <label>Address<span>(Required Field)</span>
                                <textarea  class="field size1" name="address" rows="3" cols="10"> </textarea>
                                </label>
              </p>

                  </div>
            <!-- End Form -->

                    <!-- Form Buttons -->
                    <div class="buttons" >
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button"  value="Submit" onclick="return validate(myform)" />
                      <input type="submit" name="cancel" class="button" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Form Buttons -->
                </form>
```

Comment: Poor Jean-Pierré, the man without a real name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a jsfiddle, and it wasn't calling `validate`. Removing most of your javascript and leaving just a basic `validate` did call validate. So I think your javascript has syntax errors and the form is ignoring it before submitting. So:

1. Change the cancel button to `type=button`, so that it doesn't default to submitting the form when you mean to cancel the submission.
2. Open firebug, or at the very least the javascript console (in some browsers called the 'error console') and look at the errors you get.

Learning how to debug the javascript will help this time and in the future. Javascript can be completely discarded by the browser if there are syntax errors, in which case your form will just submit as though there was no javascript at all.

Don't see that as a suggestion to only submit via javascript, however, as that would prevent users with javascript switched off from being able to use your form. But that cancel-button-that-submits has to go.

Comment: I changed the cancel button type to button. But the problem exists.I am trying to debug it.if you can debug, try this. I am not as experienced with debugging yet trying.

Comment: The error (just by getting rid of stuff and seeing if it starts working) is in ck_email; there is something syntactically wrong with it, but I'm not going to try to understand a long and complex regex like that to debug it, I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah, i checked it and placed a ; to complete it.yet the code it not working.Can you tell if we have two buttons 1.submit and 2.Cancel how to write validation for both and calling methods

Comment: No, there is something wrong with the regex itself. If you replace it with `ck_email = /./g;` then it should match everything. You have validation for the submit, the cancel can just have onclick="history.back()", or replace it with a link to the previous page.

Comment: i think my regex for mobile is not correct. I want mobile number to restrict only 10 digit numbers.I know this is simple, but the code is not working.Suggest something.

Comment: A regex for 10 digits would be: `/\d{10}/g`.

Comment: I used wrong variable name. Now the problem solved. ck_address and ck_mobile should be in place of ck_password and ck_username.Thanks for all.